# Disclaimers and declarations for potential conflicts of interest in answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Just wondering whether people posting answers should provide disclaimers or declare conflicts of interest if they refer to a particular technology or vendor solution in response to an answer that doesn't necessarily require an implementation example or solution.

I think it is good practice to state these things out in the open so we don't appear to be biased or in favour of particular products or services because we use them or have created them ourselves. Or is this something that the moderators should take into consideration when evaluating answers to these types of questions?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that it's good practice, but next to impossible to enforce.  I don't necessarily know where your conflict of interest is or isn't, so I can do little about it if you don't declare one.

Comment: Sure, it is impossible to know where the conflict of interest might exist, but if someone is advocating or promoting a particular methodology/implementation, doesn't it make sense for them to state why this is the case, especially if it is simply for the purpose of trying to 'advertise' their solution? I think moderators are the perfect people to try and pick up on things like this in the answers.

Comment: Without giving a clear example, I can't agree with you on this.